# IndexError: string index out of range for Conway's game of life tutorial

Tags: conways-game-of-life, index-error

I am following a tutorial (from https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter4/) for a text-based version of Conway's game of life, and i have put it exactly like the tutorial says and it still produces an IndexError:

the error message is as follows:

```
print(currentCells[x][y], end='')
```

IndexError: string index out of range

my goal is to place a blank space while the cells are 'alive' (meeting certain requirements) and a # when they are 'dead' (meeting other requirements)
im confused why the tutorial even when i copy directly from it, gets it wrong. the tutorial is for python 3.8

the entire block of code is as follows:

```
while True:
print('\n\n\n\n\n')
currentCells = copy.deepcopy(nextCells)
for y in range(HEIGHT):
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        print(currentCells[x][y], end='')
    print()
for x in range(WIDTH):
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        leftCoord = (x - 1) % WIDTH
        rightCoord = (x + 1) % WIDTH
        aboveCoord = (y - 1) % HEIGHT
        belowCoord = (y + 1) % HEIGHT
        numNeighbors = 0
        if currentCells[leftCoord][aboveCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1
        if currentCells[x][aboveCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1
        if currentCells[rightCoord][aboveCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1
        if currentCells[leftCoord][y] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1
        if currentCells[rightCoord][y] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1
        if currentCells[leftCoord][belowCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1
        if currentCells[x][aboveCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1
        if currentCells[rightCoord][belowCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1

        if currentCells[x][y] == '#' and (numNeighbors == 2 or numNeighbors == 3):
            nextCells[x][y] = '#'
        elif currentCells[x][y] == ' ' and numNeighbors == 3:
            nextCells[x][y] = '#'
        else:
            nextCells[x][y] = ' '
    time.sleep(1)
```

i'm new to coding so i tried commenting out the lines but of course that just renders the other parts that use those functions unusable. also the other questions on this topic seem to be about much more advanced versions of this game. like i said this is one of my first programs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too new to programming in Python! It's great language to learn:-)

Anyway I think I found the problem with the code. There is small mistake...
If you look at line 25, it says *'nextCells is a list of **column** list'*.
So instead of appending empty string is should be:

```
line 25: nextCells.append(column)
```

[image]